# What does the BTRFS warning "unhandled fiemap cache detected" mean?

Tags: kernel, btrfs

After installing Linux 4.12-rc7 mainline I'm seeing more than 100 messages in the form of

```
[ 1066.717576] btrfs_printk: 22 callbacks suppressed
[ 1066.717579] BTRFS warning (device sda5): unhandled fiemap cache detected: offset=0 phys=2900758618112 len=131072 flags=0x8
```

in `dmesg` with different `phys` values. What does that mean? Of course primarily I'm interested whether this calls for a repair or optimization, but also what it actually means in BTRFS's structure.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably fixed with this
https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9803291/

It's fixed in 4.13.